# Outputing duplicate values in 2 arraylists

Tags: java, arraylist, text-files

Hey guys I'm kind of at a cross roads here, I have two different arrayLists of different lengths and different values. I'm trying to find any common values between the two and output those to an output text file name "output.txt". I know both of the arraylist are filled with values from other textfiles, but the code I have right not with just generating an empty output textfile and I can't figure out why the program isn't outputing the duplicate values into the textfile "output.txt"

Heres the code I'm using right now:

```
public static void duplciates(){ //compares the two arrayLists dictionary and phoneWords and adds the duplicates to the duplicates arraylist
        for(String term: dictionary){
            if(phoneWords.contains(term)){
                duplicates.add(term);
            }
        }
    }

public static void openOutputFile (){
        try{
            writer = new FileWriter("E:\\output.txt");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("you have an error");
        }

    }
    public static void writeArrayToFile(){
        for(String str: duplicates){
            try {
                writer.write(str);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

If you guys have any ideas about what is wrong let me know, o if you have any better ideas on how to compare the two arraylists for the duplicate values let me know!

Comment: Close the file "writer.close()" after writing .

Answer (score 0):

Try `writer.close()` after writing.

Comment: i have that in a separate method, should I put it in the writeToArray method instead?

Answer (score 0):

Closing the writer after the for loop in  `writeArrayToFile` method would do the job.

Comment: when I do that it says there is an unhandled IOException

Comment: You can wrap that in a try-catch block.